# Change background color Javascript HTML no link

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the background colour on click and it wont seem to work. I am watching a video called Vanilla Javascript.I am comparing my code to the one in the video and I cant find the difference.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="first.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="neww.css">
    <title>Change Background Color</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-center">
            <h4>color flipper</h4>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="neww.html"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Background color : <span class="color">
                #f1f5f8
            </span>
        </h2>
            <button class="btn btn-hero" id="btn">click me</button>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="first.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
const colors = ["green", "red", "blue", "yellow"];
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const color = document.querySelector('.color');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    const randomNumber = 1;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[randomNumber];
    color.textContent = colors[randomNumber];
}
);
```

Comment: I just made a litte stackblitz with your code, and it just seemed to work ?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-s3yxwd?file=index.js

Comment: yep it worked for me too. Maybe there is some other code you didn't post that is interfering with it.

Comment: Why do you have `<script src="first.js"></script>` twice in your code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the code is that you are not generating a random number in `const randomNumber = 1;` so it will always be 1.

Since you're getting the colors from an array with 4 element. You need to generate a number between 0 and 3 (indexes of the array).

So change that line for this:
`const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 0) + 0)`. This will generate only numbers between 0 and 3.

Comment: The OP's goal is to change the background color, not get a random color.

Comment: Yeah I know, but since you are getting those colors from the array `const colors = ["green", "red", "blue", "yellow"];` if you click the button it will always access the 1 position of the array which is red. So that's the reason why the background is not changing. I mean, I just tested my solution, it's working

Comment: Run the original code. The page changes from white to red. Further clicks are trivial.

Comment: I just ran the exact same code changing the `randomNumber` variable value. It worked for me, I don't know what other problem it could have.